# This question is about search bar function searching in forms created dynamically using javascript

Tags: javascript

This is HTML code in which parent div and search bar are created. below is the code of javascript in which dynamically divs are created and in these divs forms are created but when I search something in these forms then search bar disappeared but I don't know why. Below is Javascript code in which form is created dynamically in divs and these divs append with parent div which is created in HTML. But there is an issue with search which is discussed above

```
    <div id="parentDiv"> 
                 <form id="forms">
                    <input type="search" name="search" onkeyup="searchNames()" placeholder="Serach First & Last Name" id="search"><br>
                    
                </form>
            </div>  
        <button onclick="addFields()">Click to add more fields</button>

 var id = 1;
    var divID = 1;
    function addFields()
    {
        var createDiv = document.createElement("div");
        createDiv.setAttribute("id","myDiv_"+divID);
        createDiv.setAttribute("class", "divs")
        var fieldsName = ['First Name', 'Last Name', 'Email', 'Age'];
        var idArr = ['fname', 'lname', 'email', 'age'];
        for(var i = 0; i < fieldsName.length; i++)
        {
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.name = fieldsName[i];
            input.type = "text";
            input.placeholder = fieldsName[i];
            input.id = idArr[i] + "_" + id;
            id++;
            createDiv.appendChild(input);
        }
        var delete_Row_button = document.createElement("button");
        var deleteText = document.createTextNode("Delete Row");
        delete_Row_button.appendChild(deleteText);
        createDiv.appendChild(delete_Row_button);
        delete_Row_button.onclick = function()
        {
            delete_Row_button.parentNode.remove();
        }
        divID++;
        var br = document.createElement("br");
        createDiv.appendChild(br);
        document.getElementById('parentDiv').appendChild(createDiv);
    }

And this is function named searchNames which searches the names from froms which are created in javascript dynamically. But the issue is when I search something means when I write somethng in it ten the search bar disappeared immediately. I am a beginner in JS. Kindly help me in this problem. 

    function searchNames()
            {
                var input = document.getElementById("search");
                var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
                var getDiv = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
                for(var i = 0; i < getDiv.length; i++)
                {
                   var inputTags = getDiv[i].getElementsByTagName("input");
                   for (var j = 0; j < inputTags.length; j++)
                   {
                        var inputTag = inputTags[j];
                        if(inputTag)
                        {
                            var textValue = inputTag.value;
                            var upperText = textValue.toUpperCase();
                            if(upperText.indexOf(filter) > -1)
                            {
                                getDiv[i].style.display = '';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                getDiv[i].style.display = 'none';
                            }
                        }
                   }
                }
            }
```

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` will return [an array-like HTML collection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName). You need to loop over it, or select an index from it.

Comment: still not working but this time it disappeared the search bar when I write something in it

Answer (score 0):

I had to infer a lot from you your JS to build some HTML here to make this work. Please note that `input` tags do not have `textContent` as they don't wrap things. They have values. But maybe I misunderstood your JS.

```js
function searchNames() {
  var input = document.getElementById('search');
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var getDiv = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

  for (var i = 0; i < getDiv.length; i++) {
    var inputTags = getDiv[i].getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (var o = 0; o < inputTags.length; o++) {
      var inputTag = inputTags[o];
      if (inputTag) {
        var textValue = inputTag.value;
        var upperText = textValue.toUpperCase();
        if (upperText.indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          getDiv[i].style.display = '';
        } else {
          getDiv[i].style.display = 'none';
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="search" type="text">
<div><input type="text" value="search string 1"></div>
<div><input type="text" value="search string 2"></div>
<div><input type="text" value="search string 3"></div>
<div><input type="text" value="different value"></div>
<div><input type="text" value="search string 4"></div>
<div><input type="text" value="search string 5"></div>

<button onClick="searchNames()">Search Names</button>
```